# Pynotify notify not recognizing "init" module in python

Tags: python-3.x, pynotify

I downloaded the "pynotify" package using pip.
After running the code the error is  "module 'pynotify' has no attribute 'init'"
Thank You for the help.

Comment: Here is the basic code :

import pynotify

pynotify.init("Basic")
n = pynotify.Notification("Title",
  "Some sample content"
)

n.show()

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, I'm running into the same issue

Comment: [`pynotify`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynotify) source on [Github](https://github.com/GiulioRossetti/pynotify/blob/master/pynotify/__init__.py) clearly shows that this module _does not have_ `init` member

Answer (score 1):

I don't know but it looks like to be a library conflict.

I already had the same problem and I was not able to solve it. I suggest you to try using *subprocess* that worked for me, see below:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['notify-send', "Message"])
```

Note: *notify-send* command is only Linux distributions.

You can get more *notify-send* informations [here](https://ss64.com/bash/notify-send.html).

Answer (score 0):

Because there are multiple projects called "pynotify", there's ambiguity. The one that gets installed when doing `pip install pynotify` is probably not the one you were hoping for.

```
ubuntu:~/> pip show pynotify
-->cut<--
Name: pynotify
Version: 0.1.1
Summary: Python decorator that notify via email (Gmail) the termination (and eventual stacktrace in case of failure) of a function
-->cut<--
```

Here's another one that seems to do what you want :
And I quickly tested it, it seems to work
(shows a notification toaster popup in the screen corner)
https://ms7m.github.io/notify-py/

```
ubuntu:~/> pip install notify-py

ubuntu:~/> python3
>>> from notifypy import Notify
>>> notification = Notify()
>>> notification.title = "Cool Title"
>>> notification.message = "Even cooler message."
>>> notification.send()
True
>>>
```